# Ruby single precision number

Tags: ruby, numeric, floating-accuracy

I am trying to use a COM component on Windows in Ruby which expects numbers in single precision.

In C# I am able to cast a number from double to single precision like this.

```
float mynumber =  (float)2.0
```

How can I create a single precision floating point number in Ruby?

Comment: How do you pass a number to your COM component? In Ruby all floats are stored in double precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby itself does not support single precision floats.

You can use the gem [float-formats](http://float-formats.rubyforge.org/) for doing calculations/conversion in different float formats.

But for handing an object created by this gem to a COM object you will have to convert it to the expected memory representation somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby only has one float class and it is double precision.  I haven't worked with COM in ruby, but I would expect the interface to automatically convert a ruby float to the type that it needs.  Have you tried just passing a normal ruby float to it?  What happens?  Can you post some example code demonstrating the problem?

**EDIT 1:**

You can use the pack method to convert a ruby float to a binary string that has a single precision float inside:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack

Try:

```
[2.0].pack "f"
```